# Checksum of system binaries changed

Tags: binary, md5sum, rootkit

This morning I received several OSSEC notifications about changed integrity checksums.
Affected files are `/bin/mv`, `/bin/dir`, `/bin/pwd`, `/bin/chrgrp` and about 50 similar binaries from `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

I don't have a clue how this could be happened.

Both chkrootkit and rkhunter couldn't find any rootkits, is this still something to worry about?

If so, is there a way to reinstall those system binaries?

Comment: Where there any package change entries as well? Do the changed files correspond to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/coreutils/filelist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's embarrassing but I finally figured out what has happened:
The notification was caused by an automatic security update which was released in the last days: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/coreutils/8.21-1ubuntu5.1

It was mentioned in `/var/log/dpkg.log` but I did look for an incorrect date.

Shame on me and thanks to muru for pointing this out.

Comment: It is always better to have a false alarm than to never see the alarm :) Glad you figured it out ;) kudos but no rep for @muru

Comment: @Rinzwind I've seen this exact thing happen on my OSSEC, that's why I identified it so quickly - as well OP next time around! :D